# Source location at call site and nttps: strange results and possible compiler bug?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, std-source-location

Consider the following code that uses `source_location`:

```
// Preamble
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

// Using a function
constexpr std::size_t function(
    std::size_t line = std::source_location::current().line()
) noexcept {return line;}

// Using a constructor
struct construction {
    constexpr construction(
        std::size_t input = std::source_location::current().line()
    ) noexcept: line{input} {}
    std::size_t line;
};

// Using a template deduction guide
template <std::size_t Line>
struct wrapper {
    static constexpr std::size_t line = Line;
};
template <std::size_t index = std::source_location::current().line()>
wrapper() -> wrapper<index>;

// Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::size_t f1 = function();
    std::size_t f2 = function();
    std::size_t c1 = construction().line;
    std::size_t c2 = construction().line;
    std::size_t w1 = wrapper().line;
    std::size_t w2 = wrapper().line;
    std::cout << f1 << " " << f2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << c1 << " " << c2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << w1 << " " << w2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
// GCC 12.2
28 29 // NOT EQUAL
30 31 // NOT EQUAL
23 23 // EQUAL

// CLANG 15.0
7 7   // EQUAL 
13 13 // EQUAL
23 23 // EQUAL
```

**QUESTION:**

- What should be the correct result according to the standard (in particular in the case of the wrapper?)

Comment: It looks like it is already fixed in clang on trunk. https://godbolt.org/z/vn5P85aec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the simple one: `wrapper`.

The way `source_location::current()` is defined to work is quite... specific to certain use cases. By default, the location that `current` refers to is its own location; the literal text containing the call to `current`.

[[support.srcloc.cons]/1.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/support.srcloc.cons#2) defines the following exceptions to this rule:

> *Remarks:* Any call to `current` that appears as a default member initializer ([class.mem]), or as a subexpression thereof, should correspond to the location of the constructor definition or aggregate initialization that uses the default member initializer. Any call to `current` that appears as a default argument ([dcl.fct.default]), or as a subexpression thereof, should correspond to the location of the invocation of the function that uses the default argument ([expr.call]).

You will notice that "default argument" points to a section about default *function* arguments.

Default template arguments are not default function arguments. Therefore, default template arguments are not on this list as exceptions. Therefore, `current` will always point to the location of the literal text in the code. Which will be the same for any template instantiation of `wrapper` that uses the default value.

The case of `constructor` and `function` are identical to each other. Constructors are just a kind of function, after all. And 1.2's "default argument" clause applies to both. Therefore, `current` in this context should refer to "the location of the invocation of the function that uses the default argument".

GCC complies with this. Clang does not. Clang is wrong.

Comment: Would there be a trick to make it work at the call site for wrapper?

Comment: @Vincent: Probably not. `source_location::current` is pretty clear on how it works, and anything you might try to do is going to inevitably run into that problem.